# Recommended way to configure Autofac in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-core-3.0

In ASP.NET Core 2.0, I used `ConfigureServices` method on `Startup` class to wire-up Autofac, wrap existing `services` registrations and add additional ones.

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Standard service registrations (ex: services.AddMvc())
    // ...
    
    // Autofac
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services); // wrap service registrations
    builder.RegisterModule<MyModule>(); // add extra registrations

    this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
}
```

Since `ConfigureService` method is `void` in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and no longer supports return parameter `IServiceProvider`, how do I wire up Autofac?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 `IHostBuilder` has extension method `UseServiceProviderFactory`, which can be used to register `AutofacServiceProviderFactory`:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
}
```

Registered provider will **automatically** wrap all standard services registered in `void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method.

There is **no need** for lines:

```cs
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // ...
    builder.Populate(services); // Not needed!
    // ...
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer); // Not needed!
}
```

To **add additional** Autofac-specific **registrations**, `ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)` method on startup class can be used:

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureContainer(Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterModule<MyModule>();
    }
}
```

Additional info can be found in this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2828).

Comment: Upvote for the answer and clear explanation.  Personally, I don't like the "disassociated" calls.  One call for "non-auto-fac registrations" and another call for "auto-fac-specific" registrations.

Comment: Future Reader Hint : PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="?.?.?"

Comment: Also see : https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting